# How to decrease latency of getting data from serial port?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, lag

I am using C# in Visual Studio and I created a basic interface for my sensor.

I managed to interface my interface with the serial port and I'm using the DataReceivedHandler in order to automatically update the fields when new data from the serial port is received.

However when comparing to other serial port terminals, there is quite a long delay. Any ideas of what the issue might be?

The following code snippet is for the DataReceivedHandler, could it be that I'm putting too much instructions in this section? I used the Invoke method since I could not access the textboxes any other way.

```
public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){
            string frequency = "0";
            string dataLine = ComPort.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                if(dataLine == "f")
                {
                    frequency = ComPort.ReadLine();
                }

                if(dataLine == "c")
                {
                    txtCarCount.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCarCount.Text = ComPort.ReadLine()));
                }

                txtFCount.Invoke(new Action(() => txtFCount.Text = frequency));
                fChart.Invoke(new Action(() => fChart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(frequency)));

                if (enable == 1)
                {
                    txtWrite(frequency);
                }
            }
            catch(TimeoutException)
            {
                txtCarCount.Text = "Timeout Exception";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Because of P/Invoke the serial port object has somehow worse performance than in native code. However your dispatching (Invoke() on UI thread) is now synchronous and, unless absolutely required, it's blocking the receiving thread. What to do? First of all make it asynchronous (BeginInvoke(), in WinForms no need to add EndInvoke() if you do not need result) and do it once! Dispatching is an expensive task. You can do (obviously) better, but let's start from there

Comment: you can and you should use `getters` and `setter` to access your controls instead of invoking them each time

Comment: No, he cannot call setters from another thread. Dispatching is required (but should be asynchronous and only done once)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i forgot it's opens a thread, you are right

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your comments. I replaced Invoke with BeginInvoke and although there is still latency even seconds of it it has been improved a little. Could you clarify the do it once? I was thinking of updating global variables within the DataReceivedHandler method and then updating the text fields in the general main program.

Comment: I reduced my code to the following in order to try and figure out what's causing the latency. However I am still getting a considerable amount of latency.

Comment: public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){
            dataLine = ComPort.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                if(dataLine == "f")
                {
                    frequency = ComPort.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(frequency);
                }
}
            catch(TimeoutException)
            {
                txtCarCount.Text = "Timeout Exception";
            }

        }

Comment: Those Invoke() calls pummel the UI thread pretty hard when the device is sending data at a decent clip.  Especially nasty on the chart control, if you don't throw data away there is an ever increasing number of points it needs to chart and that gets pretty noticeable in a hurry.  Eventually it starts burning 100% core and nothing updates any more.  So be sure to throw away old data.  And pay attention to elapsed time, doing this at most five or ten times per second is plenty good enough for human eyes.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for your comment as well. What would you suggest to throw away old data?